# how to save Complex json array and jsonobject in model class

Tags: android

How to get json array which is inside other jsonarray.

```
{
   "Detail":{
      "FirstName":"Raj",
      "LastName":"Yadav",
      "ConstQuestions":[
         {
            "QuestionSetId":247,
            "PathwayId":177,
            "UserId":0,
            "RuleId":0,
            "Questions":[
               {
                  "QuestionId":348,
                  "QuestionName":"Do you have excessive daytime sleepiness",
                  "choicelist":[
                     {
                        "choiceId":784,
                        "ChoiceName":"Yes"
                     },
                     {
                        "choiceId":785,
                        "ChoiceName":"No"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have above mentioned format of JSON response . I'm unable to get the choiceList array

Comment: this is an invalid json please share the correct response

Comment: get a JSONObject form JSONArray by it's index, then get a JSONArray from the JSONObject by name. Do that as many times as you need to get to the `choicelist`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. You have parse JSON response as below.

UPDATE ANSWER

First create Three lists above onCreate Method

```
List<choicelist> choicelist;
List<Questions> Questions;
List<ConstQuestions> ConstQuestions;
```

Now inside onCreate Method

```
ConstQuestions = new ArrayList();
```

Now move to function where you parse data and write this

```
choicelist = new ArrayList();
Questions = new ArrayList();
```

> THE CODE IS UPDATED

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("<YOUR STRING>");
                JSONObject detailObject = object.getJSONObject("Detail");
                String firstName = detailObject.getString("FirstName");
                String lasttName = detailObject.getString("LastName");

                JSONArray ConstQuestionsArray = detailObject.getJSONArray("ConstQuestions");
                for (int i = 0; i < ConstQuestionsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object1 = ConstQuestionsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String QuestionSetId = object1.getString("QuestionSetId");
                    String PathwayId = object1.getString("PathwayId");
                    String UserId = object1.getString("UserId");
                    String RuleId = object1.getString("RuleId");

                    JSONArray QuestionsArray = object1.getJSONArray("Questions");
                    for (int j = 0; j < QuestionsArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject object2 = QuestionsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String QuestionId = object2.getString("QuestionId");
                        String QuestionName = object2.getString("QuestionName");

                        JSONArray choicelistArray = object2.getJSONArray("choicelist");
                        for (int k = 0; k > choicelistArray.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject object3 = choicelistArray.getJSONObject(k);
                            String choiceId = object3.getString("choiceId");
                            String ChoiceName = object3.getString("ChoiceName");
                            /*UPDATED CODE*/
                            ConstQuestions.choicelist choicelists = new ConstQuestions.choicelist(choiceId, ChoiceName);
                            choicelist.add(choicelists);
                        }
                        /*UPDATED CODE*/
                        ConstQuestions.Questions questi = new ConstQuestions.Questions(QuestionId, QuestionName, choicelist);
                        Questions.add(questi);
                    }
                    /*UPDATED CODE*/
                    ConstQuestions ConstQuestionss = new ConstQuestions(QuestionSetId, PathwayId, UserId, RuleId, Questions);
                }
```

Try this and if helps, accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, :). May I know How I can make model class of it ?

Comment: For all parameters or for only selected one?

Comment: "ConstQuestions":[
         {
            "QuestionSetId":247,
            "PathwayId":177,
            "UserId":0,
            "RuleId":0,
            "Questions":[
               {
                  "QuestionId":348,
                  "QuestionName":"Do you have excessive daytime sleepiness",
                  "choicelist":[
                     {
                        "choiceId":784,
                        "ChoiceName":"Yes"
                     }, ]}]}]

Comment: for these i wanna to make model class to set value

Comment: Here is link to model class - https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/3047ffee407924ae84ea45e9d32bc39a

Comment: but how I'll add my data in it ? normally i add in this way :-

Comment: String programName = leagueData.getString("ProgramName");
 String Category = leagueData.getString("Category");
  String SubCat = leagueData.getString("SubCat");
 PlanPojo planPojo = new PlanPojo();
  planPojo.setAmpm(Ampm);

Comment: Actually @Shane Sir, I'm developing 1 quiz app where firstly I'll get json data which will display qus with 3 option .

Comment: Unable to save list data in model class @Shane sir

Answer (score 0):

You can Achieve List by below code.

```
 String s="Your JSON String";
    try {
        JSONObject main=new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject detail=main.getJSONObject("Detail");
        JSONArray ConstQuestions=detail.getJSONArray("ConstQuestions");
        for(int l=0;l<ConstQuestions.length();l++){
            JSONObject OBJ=ConstQuestions.getJSONObject(l);
            JSONArray choicelistArray=OBJ.getJSONArray("choicelist");
              for (int k = 0; k < choicelistArray.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject object3 =choicelistArray.getJSONObject(k);
                        String choiceId = object3.getString("choiceId");
                        String ChoiceName = object3.getString("ChoiceName");
              }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here choicelistArray is your choice list array

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below model class using that you achieve what you want:



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class ComplexModel implements Serializable{

    @SerializedName("Detail")
    @Expose
    private Detail detail;

    public Detail getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(Detail detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public class Detail implements Serializable{

        @SerializedName("FirstName")
        @Expose
        private String firstName;
        @SerializedName("LastName")
        @Expose
        private String lastName;
        @SerializedName("ConstQuestions")
        @Expose
        private List<ConstQuestion> constQuestions = null;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public List<ConstQuestion> getConstQuestions() {
            return constQuestions;
        }

        public void setConstQuestions(List<ConstQuestion> constQuestions) {
            this.constQuestions = constQuestions;
        }

        public class ConstQuestion implements Serializable{

            @SerializedName("QuestionSetId")
            @Expose
            private Integer questionSetId;
            @SerializedName("PathwayId")
            @Expose
            private Integer pathwayId;
            @SerializedName("UserId")
            @Expose
            private Integer userId;
            @SerializedName("RuleId")
            @Expose
            private Integer ruleId;
            @SerializedName("Questions")
            @Expose
            private List<Question> questions = null;

            public Integer getQuestionSetId() {
                return questionSetId;
            }

            public void setQuestionSetId(Integer questionSetId) {
                this.questionSetId = questionSetId;
            }

            public Integer getPathwayId() {
                return pathwayId;
            }

            public void setPathwayId(Integer pathwayId) {
                this.pathwayId = pathwayId;
            }

            public Integer getUserId() {
                return userId;
            }

            public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
                this.userId = userId;
            }

            public Integer getRuleId() {
                return ruleId;
            }

            public void setRuleId(Integer ruleId) {
                this.ruleId = ruleId;
            }

            public List<Question> getQuestions() {
                return questions;
            }

            public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
                this.questions = questions;
            }

            public class Question implements Serializable{

                @SerializedName("QuestionId")
                @Expose
                private Integer questionId;
                @SerializedName("QuestionName")
                @Expose
                private String questionName;
                @SerializedName("choicelist")
                @Expose
                private List<Choicelist> choicelist = null;

                public Integer getQuestionId() {
                    return questionId;
                }

                public void setQuestionId(Integer questionId) {
                    this.questionId = questionId;
                }

                public String getQuestionName() {
                    return questionName;
                }

                public void setQuestionName(String questionName) {
                    this.questionName = questionName;
                }

                public List<Choicelist> getChoicelist() {
                    return choicelist;
                }

                public void setChoicelist(List<Choicelist> choicelist) {
                    this.choicelist = choicelist;
                }

            }

            public class Choicelist implements Serializable{

                @SerializedName("choiceId")
                @Expose
                private Integer choiceId;
                @SerializedName("ChoiceName")
                @Expose
                private String choiceName;

                public Integer getChoiceId() {
                    return choiceId;
                }

                public void setChoiceId(Integer choiceId) {
                    this.choiceId = choiceId;
                }

                public String getChoiceName() {
                    return choiceName;
                }

                public void setChoiceName(String choiceName) {
                    this.choiceName = choiceName;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

and after that check:

```
ComplexModel.Detail complexModel = new ComplexModel().new Detail();
    ArrayList<ComplexModel.Detail.ConstQuestion.Choicelist> choicelists = new ArrayList<>();

    if (complexModel.getConstQuestions() != null) {
        if (complexModel.getConstQuestions().get(0).getQuestions() != null) {
            for (int i=0;i<complexModel.getConstQuestions().get(0).getQuestions().size();i++) {
                if (complexModel.getConstQuestions().get(0).getQuestions().get(i).getChoicelist() != null) {
                    choicelists.addAll(complexModel.getConstQuestions().get(0).getQuestions().get(i).getChoicelist());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Using this You are easily achieving what you want.

Comment: SerializedName  and Expose both r in red color

Comment: I have resolved this error issue . now plz let me know how i can add my list of json data in this?

Comment: now when server call complete put whole data into model which i define above

Comment: store response into the ***complexModel*** this class model and after that put  ***if*** condition which i mention in answer